# Regular Expression for Bank Account Number?

Tags: regex

I need to write a regular expression to check for valid bank account number format of major banks in USA and Canada (I already know the format for transit number and institution number, but I don't know the format for account number).  Does anyone know what regular expression check should be?  Perhaps I just check to make sure all characters are digits?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The US doesn't conform to IBAN standards for account numbers; AFAIK there is no definitive US standard for account numbers, just for routing numbers.

Answer (score 5):

I believe phoebus is correct - there's simply no guaranteed standards compliance in the case of the USA, so a regex isn't as helpful as one might imagine.

Account numbers complying with the [ACH (Automated Clearing House)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_Clearing_House) network standard can have up to 17 alphanumeric characters - the problem is not all financial transactions are ACH. (SEE also [united-states-banking-institution-account-number-regular-expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540285/united-states-banking-institution-account-number-regular-expression/1540314#1540314))

According to this [patent document](http://www.patentstorm.us/patents/7225155/description.html):

> *For field 5, located at position 13-39, DFI account number entails 17 characters, which the example shows as allowing any alphanumeric form.*

Page 25 of [State of California Tax Francise Board EFT Program Guide](http://www.ftb.ca.gov/forms/misc/3817.pdf) agrees with the above.

**So, to a least check ACH format compliance, check for 1 to 17 alpha-numerics**:

```
^\w{1,17}$
```

A resource that show a specific use of the ACH standard:
http://ribbs.usps.gov/ncsc_ach_pay_instruct/documents/tech_guides/Memphis_NCSC_ACH_Credit_Payment_Option.pdf

Answer (score 1):

There is not a US standard for bank account numbers. However, NACHA provides a [specification](http://achrulesonline.org/achrules.aspx#p118) for ACH transactions which states for an example Account Number field (DFI Account Number):

> The leftmost 17 characters are inserted in the DFI Account Number
>   field and the remaining characters truncated. ... If fewer than 17
>   characters, left justify and leave the unused spaces blank.

The DFI Account Number field as part of the [CCD Entry Detail](http://achrulesonline.org/achrules.aspx#p92) is indicated as '[alphameric](http://achrulesonline.org/achrules.aspx#p73)' (ASCII values greater than 0x1F).

Here is the regex I came up with. It doesn't match on the full ASCII range but I think it will handle most account numbers. (17 characters long composed of word,-,. alphanumeric leading. rightpad with spaces. if dash present-not consecutive and not at end)

```
^(?<DFIAccountNumber>(?=[\w\- ]{17})[0-9A-Za-z](\-?\w+)*[ ]*)
```