# Regex for Bank Account Number and Bank Routing Number

Tags: regex, format

Does anyone know which is the format for these two criteria?

```
Bank Account Number

Bank Routing Number
```

I am interested in what format regex for two.

I look forward to a response from you

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would imagine each country, if not each bank, has its own format. We need more information, and, of course, please make an attempt to solve the problem first yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [United States Banking Institution Account Number Regular Expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540285/united-states-banking-institution-account-number-regular-expression)

Answer (score 4):

Routing numbers (at least in the US) are always 9 digits. See [routing numbers on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_transit_number) for a thorough breakdown of how the routing number is structured and what values are acceptable. (Note: Regex is almost certainly **not** what you want to use to validate these.)

Account numbers are of arbitrary length and value, as defined by the individual bank. It cannot be validated without checking with the bank in question.

All this, and more, was asked and answered in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540285/united-states-banking-institution-account-number-regular-expression).